# Как сделать кнопку зависимую от чекбоксов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть таблица в которой в каждой строке по чекбоксу и есть кнопка вне таблицы. Надо чтобы если хоть один чекбокс выбран кнопка была активной - иначе не активной (`disabled`). Проблема в том что `disabled` это атрибут, а не стиль. Значит через CSS это не сделаешь. Я пытался через `jquery` повесить на все чекбоксы событие `change` и в нем менять активность кнопки, но это корявое решение которое не всегда работает почему-то. Есть способ получше?

P.S. Забыл уточнить. На этой странице используется `Pjax` для обновления данных таблицы (проект на Yii2). Возможно из-за него как раз и проблема с рандомно работающими событиями.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словами _"корявое решение которое не всегда работает почему-то"_? У вас событие не правильно срабатывало или что?

Comment: Некоторые разработчике прибегают к другой технологии, они не "дисеблят" кнопку подтверждения, а лишь при её клике делают проверку, и если не один чекбокс (в вашем случае) не выбран, выводят сообщение об ошибке с просьбой выбрать 1 из пунктов

Comment: @RifmaMan да - иногда не срабатывает событие по какой-то причине

Comment: Возможно вам стоит использовать другое событие, ни **change**, а скажем **click** или **mouseup**, **mousedown**. Важный момент когда именно событие происходит, а там вы уже сможете сделать я думаю проверку на выбранные (отмеченные) галочки.

Comment: @RifmaMan Добавил важное уточнение в вопрос

Comment: Если вы динамически подгружаете элементы то вы должны в тотже момент вешать на них события, либо использовать конструкцию `$(docuemnt).on('mousedown', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {...});`, которая, вешает событие на все элементы input типа checkbox даже если они были добавлены после загрузки страницы, в таком случае события будут действовать всегда, я думаю в этом и была ваша проблема.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```js
var $checkboxes = $("table input:checkbox"), 
    $btn = $("#btn");

$checkboxes.each(function(idx, itm){
  $(itm).on("change", function() {
    var isCheckedAnything = $checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > 0;
    $btn.prop('disabled', !isCheckedAnything);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Checkbox 1</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chBox1" value="1" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Checkbox 2</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chBox2" value="2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Checkbox 3</td><td><input type="checkbox" name="chBox3" value="3" /></td></tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" disabled="true" />
```

#### Дополнение

В комментариях предлагалось использовать события `click` и даже `mousedown` `mouseup`, но хочу Вас предупредить, что событие `change` как бы "виртуальное", т.е. оно происходит при смене значения вне зависимости от способа.
Чекбокс можно отметить:

- клавиатурой при использовании <kbd>Tab</kbd> и <kbd>Пробел</kbd>;
- мышью;
- "тапом" при использовании мобильного девайса;

Comment: Добавил важное уточнение в вопрос

Comment: `"тапом" при использовании мобильного девайса;` (c) — ого, а есть отдельный ивент для "тапа" ? Думал это тот же click...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

Answer (score 0):

Такой вариант скорее всего сработает:

```js
let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');
let check = document.getElementsByClassName('check');
for( let i = 0; i < check.length; i++ ){
  check[i].addEventListener('change', function(){
    /* После каждого клика заново перебираем отмеченные чекбоксы */
    let c = document.querySelectorAll('.check:checked');
    /* Строчка ниже называется "тернарный оператор", его общий вид:
       (условие) ? "Значение при выполнении" : "Значение в остальных случаях"
       Здесь проверяем - если кол-во отмеченных больше нуля, будет 
       bubu.disabled = false, иначе - true */
    bubu.disabled = ( c.length > 0 ) ? false : true;
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>td-1</td>
    <td><input class="check" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td-2</td>
    <td><input class="check" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td-3</td>
    <td><input class="check" type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="bubu" disabled>bubu</button>
```